# Knowing whether Python call via xlwings succeeded or not in VBA

Tags: python, xlwings

To call python from within the spreadsheet, I do RunPython(), but does this return a success or failure code? How do I know in VBA whether the call succeeded or not? I guess one option I have is to let the python function write to a cell in the spreadsheet and then let VBA check it's value, but I'm wondering if there's a better, more native/intended way to do it.

Comment: How is RunPython() defined? Is it a Sub or a Function, and if it's Function what is its return type?

Comment: This is xlwing's built-in macro i believe. I don't see anything returning from it

Comment: How would I be able to see it or use it in VBA? (do I need to set a reference or is it an AddIn)

Comment: I'm specifically asking about xlwings. If you are not familiar with it I will wait for an expert on the subject. Thank you.

Comment: In that case please remove the tags excel, vba, and excel-vba. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In its current implementation, xlwings is designed to completely hand over control to Python once you call `RunPython`, i.e. no return value, but it will show a popup with the error, should there be one. The reason for this is cross-platform compatibility, see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30930218/how-to-wait-for-xlwings-to-complete-python-code-in-vba) discussion about how to deal with VBA code that is supposed to come after your `RunPython` call.

Comment: Do you then recommend letting the python procedure setting a hidden cell in Excel and letting VBA check the value of that cell then?

Comment: Following the previous question, should I be able to direct the Error output to a cell and suppressing the error window?

Comment: You can add a feature request for that on GitHub and we can continue the discussion there...